# How to create .bat file which runs python script?

Tags: python

I have follow the instructions from tutorials like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" "C:\myfolder\myfile.py"
pause
```

but the script does not work and windows shouts:
that the path `]]"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" "C:\myfolder\myfile.py"` is incorrect.
Those `]]` are strange 2 characters: [image]

Maybe the .bat file contains some hidden characters?

Comment: Yes, maybe that is the case. Did you check it?

Comment: the path is OK. I can run it from comand line: `python C:\myfolder\myfile.py`

Answer (score 0):

You might be using notpad++ and saving as UTF-8; try encoding/saving the file as plain ascii or "UTF-8 without BOM".

Comment: it is saved with UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: I just tried to save with BOM and get exactly the same error.

Comment: `Encode in UTF-8`... when i convert to `Encode in UTF-8-BOM` same error occurs

Comment: The same issue with plain ascii? Or copy-paste in os notepad :) I really suspect it's a kind of encoding issue...